# Cordova call plugin code from appdelegate IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build a plug in for a Cordova App. In this plug in I have some native code for push notifications. I have added the files needed inside the plug in and now i am trying to call a header from app's AppDelegate.m. But the import has the error "file not found". I have added the header file in the plugin's plugin.xml as: < header-file src="src/ios/xxxxx/xxxxx.h" />
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppDelegate.m` is auto-generated when Cordova creates the iOS platform project so making direct modifications to it is not recommended since if you rebuild the platform project with `cordova plugin rm ios && cordova platform add ios`, any changes will be lost.

Plugins can work around this by using a category extension to the `AppDelegate` class which allows you to bundle code which extends the AppDelegate in your plugin repo without affecting the auto-generated file.

For example, you would create `myplugin/src/ios/AppDelegate+MyPlugin.h`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate (MyPlugin) <UIApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

Then in `myplugin/src/ios/AppDelegate+MyPlugin.m` you can implement your app delegate, for example:

```
#import "AppDelegate+MyPlugin.h"

@implementation AppDelegate (MyPlugin)


// A UIApplication delegate
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Remote notification received");
}

...
```

To allow your AppDelegate category to interact with your Cordova plugin class, you can expose a public method which returns its singleton instance which the AppDelegate category can call; for example:

`myplugin/src/ios/MyPlugin.h`:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin

// Public static method
+ (MyPlugin*) myPlugin;

// A public instance method
- (void)logMessage: (NSString*)msg;

@end
```

`myplugin/src/ios/MyPlugin.m`:

```
#import "MyPlugin.h"

@implementation MyPlugin

// Private static reference
static MyPlugin* myplugin;

// Public static method
+ (MyPlugin*) myplugin {
    return myplugin;
}


// implement CDVPlugin delegate
- (void)pluginInitialize {
    myplugin = self;
}


// A public instance method
- (void)logMessage: (NSString*)msg
{
    NSLog(@"MyPlugin: %@", msg);
}

@end
```

Then in `myplugin/src/ios/AppDelegate+MyPlugin.m` you can make use of your plugin methods:

```
#import "AppDelegate+MyPlugin.h"
#import "MyPlugin.h"

@implementation AppDelegate (MyPlugin)


// A UIApplication delegate
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    [MyPlugin.myPlugin logMessage:@"Remote notification received"];
}

...
```

An example of a plugin which takes this approach is [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i can not understand how this new implementation is supposed to run on the initialization of the app?

Comment: `AppDelegate+MyPlugin` is a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) which extends the existing `AppDelegate` class and therefore any delegate methods it implements will be added to the main `AppDelegate` class and invoked appropriately. But if you want to explicitly run initialisation in the category you can [swizzle `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2BFirebasePlugin.m#L31).